# ResponseEntityExceptionHandler error with new Spring Boot version

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception, exceptionhandler

Although I could use `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` with the previous Spring Boot versions as shown on [this](https://github.com/thombergs/code-examples/blob/master/spring-boot/exception-handling/src/main/java/io/reflectoring/exception/exception/GlobalExceptionHandler.java) example, I get the following error for the `handleExceptionInternal` method when I implement the same exception handler in my new app (Spring Boot version 3.0.2):

> Method does not override method from its superclass

So, I can fix the problem by not extending `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`, but I am not sure if there is a better way to fix this problem.

Any idea for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The signature of the method is different so now you get that error. Check signature [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.html#handleExceptionInternal(java.lang.Exception,java.lang.Object,org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders,org.springframework.http.HttpStatusCode,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest)).

Basically what you need to change is: `HttpStatus` --> `HttpStatusCode`

Here is an example of overriding this method:

```
 @Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleExceptionInternal(Exception ex,
    Object body,
    HttpHeaders headers,
    HttpStatusCode statusCode,
    WebRequest request){
    
    //your code here....

}
```

Comment: Yes, veeerry veerry interesting., voted up ;)  But why? Did it changed in the last version(s)? And is it good to change HttpStatus --> HttpStatusCode ? I mean the former and latter are the same type? Any idea?